# Attempt to apply Quotient Rule backwards

Tags: calculus

If Quotient Rule can be taken backwards I believe it  introduces newer constants indefinitely depending  on the order of integration.

We have in case of differentiation w.r.t $t$ when $ \dfrac{y}{x}$ = constant=$c$, by successive application of Quotient Rule,

$$ \dfrac{y^{}}{x^{}}= \dfrac{y^{'}}{x^{'}}= \dfrac{y^{''}}{x^{''}}= \dfrac{y^{'''}}{x^{'''}}=...= c .$$

Similarly then, how are the successively higher integrates $y^{(-1)},y^{(-2)},x^{(-1)},x^{(-2)}.. $ shown to be related with newer constants of integration thrown in ?

EDIT1

Explaining what I mean is not easy, so may I seek your indulgence.

Quotient Rule when applied to a function value $ y/x = c $ gives on differentiation

$$ \frac{y}{x} = \frac{y^{'}}{x^{'}}$$

We could deliberate on how we may or may not try to operate it backwards

$$ \frac{y'}{x'} = \frac{y+c_1}{x+ c_2}$$

A simple example below is the case is provided when constants of integration are chosen $1$ and $C_1=0$ for getting correct value at x=0 which can be checked by by L Hospital's Rule in the normal forward way.

$$  \frac{\sin x }{x} = \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2/2+C_1} $$

The above is straight forward with a single variable (x), but not so with multi-variable situations.

Let me give the example that prompted the post:

[image: QuotientRule Backwards]

The above is a circle of diameter $d$ touching the x-axis with a differential equation:

$$ \frac {\sin \psi}{r} = \frac{1}{d}$$

With the above initiative we have

$$ \frac{1}{d} =\frac{d \psi}{ds}= \frac{\cos \psi\, d\psi}{\cos \psi \,ds}=\frac{\cos \psi\, d\psi}{dr}=  \frac{\int \cos \psi\, d\psi}{\int dr}= \frac{\sin \psi + C_2}{r+ C_3}   $$

Now only when $C_2= C_3=0 $ our original circle is recovered. Three other cases that appear spurious (they are three new types of distorted spirals found by numerical integration)

The import of this is:

$ \dfrac {\sin \psi}{r} = \dfrac{1}{d}$ is something and $ \frac{d\psi}{ds}$ is something else.

To sum it up, in Integral Calculus, how do integral solutions represented by

$$ \dfrac{f^{(-2)}}{g^{(-2)}} = c,\; \dfrac{f^{(-1)}}{g^{(-1)}} =c,\;\dfrac{f}{g}  = c $$

relate to each other?

Can a partial differential equation be written relating (x,y), (X,Y) with the same  integrate quotient $c$

$$ \frac{y}{x} = \frac{Y}{X} = c $$

to be generally solved?

If we say by inspection we can arrive at a choice, that does not sound like a Rule...At most we may say it is a way to generalize by catching on a constant, but how exactly is it classified in theory in accommodating new constants $C_2,C_3 $, i.e., in what new situations .. is the question here.

Hope I could convey in part at least.. if not I would reply to comments and clarifications

Comment: Your question is not at all clear, and neither is your notation for "higher integrates." Please clarify.

Comment: Perhaps, think of higher integrates as lower derivatives e.g. $$f^{(n)}, \dots, f^{(2)}, f^{(1)}, f, f^{(-1)}, f^{(-2)}, \dots, f^{(-n)}$$

Comment: @JohnJoy, thanks, shall modify that way, using negative "exponents".

Comment: For a second I thought I understood what your question was - given $y(t)/x(t)=c$ find antiderivatives $Y$ and $X$ for which $Y(t)/X(t)=c$ as well - but then reading the "simple example" I have to say I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Please ignore the simple example. ( Their complex roots elsewhere behave quite differently ...all even and all multiples of $\pi$ respectively ). If you think it is compromising the question, shall delete that part.